# Should we use pre-bundled javascript file in WordPress project?

Tags: wordpress, module, webpack, requirejs, bundle

Recently I tried to use module system like requirejs/browserify/webpack for my wordpress project, the main purpose is bundle assets(javascript, css files etc).

But there is a problem I'm confusing: Should we use pre-bundled javascript file in WordPress theme/plugin project?

The Pros of pre-bundled script is reduce requests and improve performance, so why this is a problem?

Because usually a wordpress website is not just use one theme but many plugins. If a wordpress module(theme/plugin) used pre-bundled scripts, it may results that same script loaded by different modules and users have no choice to dequeue it.

For example:

#### pre-bundle

my theme `A` use a pre-bundled scripts file `bundle.js` which included lodash, backbone, jquery, carousel plugin, bootstrap..., a user used my theme on their site, and activated many plugins, some of plugins enqueued backbone, bootstrap or other same plugins. Even we can resolve conflict problem, the site will load same library/plugins many times to result unnecessary extra load time of page.

#### post-bundle

if we use WordPress way `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` to load script separately and implement assets dependecies. The users can dequeue script with `wp_dequeue_script()` when there is same script used in different modules, and users can use some minfiy/merge plugin to merge all scripts, which I called post-bundle.

So, question again, Should we use pre-bundled javascript file in WordPress project? or do you have a suggestion for what is best way to organize scripts in WordPress project?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for your case? I have same problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is certainly something you should be doing. I do not have much experience with WordPress, so it's not very clear how this could be accomplished respecting the fact that the list of scripts is dynamically evaluated for each request.

One thing that would be possible, I believe, is to create a static bundle for a certain set of scripts, say `foo.js`, `bar.js` and `quux.js`, and then do something along the lines:

- evaluate all the scripts before they are rendered in the HTML output
- for each script, check if it is part of a bundle
- if so, dequeue the script, mark the bundle as being included
- at the end, enqueue all the bundles that should be included

Obviously, this would require a lot of tooling and sharing data between PHP and JS and it's not something that you could easily drop into a WP instance, because you'd probably have to make some manual changes, say, every time the list of plugins changes. Though, since you would have complete control over the bundle, you could certainly achieve greater optimizations beyond the simple "take HTML response, extract scripts, concatenate and minify, transform response" approach most WP owners are settling for.